# Insert string with ' in a table from another table with sql

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I need to insert values from lists into a table with python
Two lists are say:

```
A = [(1,2,Don't Use), (2,4, None), (3,None, Need "Access")
```

I tried to use pyodbc and sql command.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO New_Table(SL, ID, text)

       VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s)" % (A[i][0], A[i][1], A[i][2])
```

It works good when the text don't have special character like `"` or `'`. I am searching the way to make this happen as I am new to this programming thing

Comment: It's called a `single quote` or `quotation mark`. Those terms are more searchable.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted#Parameters

Comment: Never use Python string replacement with SQL as your code will be open for SQL injections and other security vunerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need single-quotes here. The `pyodbc` module will handle any quoting for you. Simply use the appropriate placeholder (`?`), and pass a tuple of your parameters as the 2nd argument to `.execute()`. For example:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('your connection string')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO New_Table(SL, ID, text)
                  VALUES (?,?,?);""", (A[i][0], A[i][1], A[i][2]))
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

As mentioned in a comment, if you instead use string-interpolation to form your query you open your application up to [SQL-Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.

Comment: Thanks bernie... I did the same thing that cursor.execute(sql).  What I did not know is using double quote three times.  Thanks anyway

Comment: Oh, the triple-quote is for multi-line strings. You're welcome.